# SQL Data Migration: directly updating the DB/Cache vs updating via REST API calls

Tags: sql, database, go, data-migration

We have come across a situation where we need to separate one column (`old_col`) into 3 different columns (`new_col1, new_col2, new_col3`) in the SQL db.

*We have already come up with a business logic of separating the value inside `old_col` into the `new_cols`.*

**Current Data Migration Strategy:-**

Use existing REST API to update(PUT) all the rows. The `update` API has the business logic built in it.

Cons:

- taking too long
- unnecessary load on the server

**Proposed Strategy:-**

Directly update the DB values using a script

Cons:

- Need to invalidate the cache
- Multiple services reading from the DB

*I know this is very little information, but in general what is the best strategy to go ahead with the problem statement and what else can we do/explore to reduce our risks?*

Backend: GoLang

DB: SQL

No of Records: 5 million

Comment: SQL isn't a database. Do you mean SQL Server? Please update tags accordingly. What cache are you using? You'd need to refresh it. Updating 5 million records one at a time via REST API will take you years. You definitely need to run a script to do it

Comment: Every relational database is a "SQL database"